# Generate Java classes with JAXB from a DTD file - how can I modify the DTD?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, dtd

I want to generate Java classes from a dtd file using JAXB.

The dtd looks like this:

```
<!--Contents-->
    <!ELEMENT persons (header, content) >
    <!ELEMENT groups (header, content) >

<!--Header-->
    <!ELEMENT header (version) >
    <!ELEMENT version(#PCDATA) >

<!--Content-->
    <!ELEMENT content(person, group)* >

<!--Person-->
    <!ELEMENT person(p_id, p_name) >
    <!ELEMENT p_id (#PCDATA) >
    <!ELEMENT p_name (#PCDATA) >    

<!--Group-->
    <!ELEMENT group(g_id) >
    <!ELEMENT g_id(#PCDATA) >
```

When generating the classes with JAXB I get the following ones:

- ObjectFactory
- Content
- Person
- Persons
- Group
- Groups

In the Content class the method to retreive all the persons and groups is

```
public List<Object> getPersonOrGroup() {
    if (personOrGroup == null) {
        personOrGroup = new ArrayList<Object>();
    }
    return this.personOrGroup;
}
```

Is there anything I can change in the dtd file so the generation of Java classes will make the `persons` and `groups` separated in the `Content` java class, so to retreive all persons and groups would be to make a call to `Content.getPersons()` and `Content.getGroups()` respectivly?

Comment: Dont think that possible.Take a look into this.https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1624187

Comment: it is definitely possibly. http://www.javaworld.com/community/node/7622

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In his response, mavrav seems to tell that it's impossible with DTD. I don't know well how to use DTD.
But if you can, translate your DTD in XML schema.

I tried with this shema:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:hr="http://mycompany.com/schema"
        elementFormDefault="qualified"
        targetNamespace="http://mycompany.com/schema">
    <!-- Contents -->
    <xs:element name="persons">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="header" />
                <xs:element name="content" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="groups">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="header" />
                <xs:element name="content" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <!-- Header -->
    <xs:element name="header">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="version" type="xs:string" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <!-- Content -->
    <xs:element name="content">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="person" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                <xs:element name="group" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <!-- Person -->
    <xs:element name="person">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="p_id" type="xs:integer" />
                <xs:element name="p_name" type="xs:string" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <!-- Group -->
    <xs:element name="group">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="g_id" type="xs:integer" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

After I generated Java classes with the following cmd:

```
xjc -p com.mypackage schema.xsd
```

And it gives me the following code for the Content class:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "content")
public class Content {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected List<Object> person;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected List<Object> group;

    public List<Object> getPerson() {
        if (person == null) {
            person = new ArrayList<Object>();
        }
        return this.person;
    }

    public List<Object> getGroup() {
        if (group == null) {
            group = new ArrayList<Object>();
        }
        return this.group;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 16):

```
xjc -dtd -d generatedsrc -p com.examples log4j.dtd
```

will generate the classes in directory generatedsrc and the package used will be com.examples.

you can find more information here:
http://www.javaworld.com/community/node/7622

Comment: I don't think that article answers @Rox question. His problem is that when generating the Java code from the DTD xjc creates a single List<Object> whenever an element can hold more than one type of data, mixing objects of different classes. I have the same problem. The article only explains how to generate Java code from DTD using xjc, and doesn't even mention this particular case.