# JAXB serializer from java objects to xml

Tags: java, xml, jaxp, dtd

I'm a newbie of XML programming, I'm trying to write some java objects to a well formed and valid XML file (with respect to a DTD file),

I found out that I can do this kind of things using JAXP with Java.
My application is going to retrieve some data using an interface, and then I need to write that data into an XML file with respect of a DTD I previously and already created.

I tried to find some informations about this operations but I failed.

How am I supposed to do this operation?

EDIT: Please note that I need to stick with DTD (Can't switch to a XML schema) and that I need to go FROM Java Objects TO XML, and not viceversa.
I found that the Duplicated Answer is not applying for my question.

Don't know if the DTD can be of any help, but here it is.

DTD

```
<!ELEMENT AIRCRAFTS (AIRCRAFT+)>
<!ELEMENT AIRCRAFT (MODEL, SEATS)>
<!ELEMENT MODEL (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT SEATS (SEAT+)>
<!ELEMENT SEAT (#PCDATA)>

<!ELEMENT FLIGHTS (FLIGHTREADER+)>
<!ELEMENT FLIGHTREADER (DEPARTURE, TIME, DESTINATION)>
<!ELEMENT DEPARTURE (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT TIME (HOUR, MINUTE)>
<!ELEMENT HOUR (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT MINUTE (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT DESTINATION (#PCDATA)>


<!ELEMENT FLIGHTINSTANCES (FLIGHTINSTANCEREADER+)>
<!ELEMENT FLIGHTINSTANCEREADER (AIRCRAFTID, DATE, DELAY, DEPARTUREGATE, FLIGHTREADERID, PASSENGERREADER+, STATUS)>
<!ELEMENT AIRCRAFTID (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT DATE (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT DELAY (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT DEPARTUREGATE (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT FLIGHTREADERID (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT PASSENGERREADER (NAME, FLIGHTINSTANCEID, SEATID, BOARDED)>
<!ELEMENT FLIGHTINSTANCEID (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT BOARDED (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT NAME (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT SEATID (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT STATUS (#PCDATA)>

<!ATTLIST FLIGHTINSTANCEREADER id ID #REQUIRED>
<!ATTLIST FLIGHTREADER id ID #REQUIRED>
<!ATTLIST AIRCRAFT id ID #REQUIRED>
```

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10312159/generate-java-classes-with-jaxb-from-a-dtd-file-how-can-i-modify-the-dtd#answer-14927126) answers your question. I should know, I tried this recently and it worked.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I don't think the question is duplicated, the one you linked me is not answering my question and doesn't satisfy the constraints I have

Comment: The answer link I provided allows you to generate Java Objects from DTD (using `xjc` which comes with the JDK in the `bin` folder). It will not create an XML schema but you can still use JAXB to generate XML from Java Object. Creating a schema from the DTD can be daunting.

Comment: Firstly, thank you again for your time.
What I need to do is to generate a valid XML (with respect to a DTD) starting from some java objects.

I don't want to create Java Objects from a DTD, that's not my goal.
I already have the Java objects, and I want to write them down to a valid XML file using JAXP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's basically the same way to convert Java Object to XML with `JAXBContext` and `Marshaller` with an addition of validation the XML validation with DTD.

See the sample code:

```
    SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
    SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
    XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();

    JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance("blog.log4j");
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
    UnmarshallerHandler unmarshallerHandler = unmarshaller.getUnmarshallerHandler();
    xr.setContentHandler(unmarshallerHandler);

    FileInputStream xmlStream = new FileInputStream("src/blog/log4j/sample1.xml");
    InputSource xmlSource = new InputSource(xmlStream);
    xr.parse(xmlSource);

    Log4JConfiguration config = (Log4JConfiguration) unmarshallerHandler.getResult();

    Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
    marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
    marshaller.marshal(config, System.out);
```

[Source](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/jaxb-and-dtd.html).

Answer (score -1):

First you need to serialize object to xml, then you need validate id against dtd.

[Here](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0470.html) 
you have example how to serialzie classes to xml.

[This one](http://www.javablog.fr/javaxml-validating-xml-with-dtd-document-type-definition-or-xsd-xml-schema-definition-with-jaxp-sax-dom-standard-apis.html) shows how to validate xml file with dtd that is outside or inside xml file.

Comment: The question is about how to serialize the object in XML according to some DTD. This is not addressed in your answer.