# XML deserialization into Java object using Jackson

Tags: java, xml, jackson

I am struggling since few hours to parse this xml into Java object. Couldn't find enough tutorials with examples.

```
<smil 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/SMIL20/Language">
    <head>
        <meta name="title" content="b3144064-dee8-4757-b081-a20f4c51e3b9" />
        <meta name="httpBase" content="https://a.akamaihd.net/" />
        <meta name="vod" content="true"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <switch id="b3144064-dee8-4757-b081-a20f4c51e3b9">
            <video src="b3144064-dee8-4757-b081-a20f4c51e3b9_150.mp4" system-bitrate="150000"/>
            <video src="b3144064-dee8-4757-b081-a20f4c51e3b9_550.mp4" system-bitrate="550000"/>
            <video src="b3144064-dee8-4757-b081-a20f4c51e3b9_1500.mp4" system-bitrate="1500000"/>
            <video src="b3144064-dee8-4757-b081-a20f4c51e3b9_2000.mp4" system-bitrate="2000000"/>
        </switch>
    </body>
</smil>
```

Comment: There is a [DTD](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-smil/smil-DTD.html). Maybe this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14927126/3493036) helps.

Comment: thank you @Patrick